# ggplot: display group and time interaction (2x2) with boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape, boxplot

I've seen several example with ggplot2 and reshapre library. But my final result still overlays my boxplots. I've not seen any simple example on a 2x2 boxplot-design (group and time interaction) yet. I only have one data-frame.

```
ggplot(aes(y = DV, x = "Group and Time", col = df$group), data = df) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = df$y1, x=df$group, col="T1")) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = df$y2, x=df$group, col="T2"))
```

[image]

Colour for T2 (blue) overlays T1-colour (red). My minimal example looks somehow like this:

```
set.seed(1234)
x<- sample(c("exp", "con"), 100, replace = TRUE)
yT1<-rnorm(100)
yT2<-rnorm(100)
df<- (as.data.frame(cbind(x,yT1,yT2)))
head(df)

    x                yT1                  yT2
1 exp  0.405002805433516     1.94871306497599
2 exp   0.97580332180945    0.933816332207727
3 con -0.348876736539909     1.91305942169705
4 con  0.158625439491262 -0.00523405793193957
5 exp  -1.76325506654115   -0.152260048921635
6 exp  0.338596047099905   -0.509631657179118

ggplot(aes(y = DV, x = "group and time", col = df$x), data = df) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = df$yT1, x=df$x, col="T1")) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = df$yT2, x=df$x, col="T2"))
```

I know that my minimal example lacks some kind of class-transformation (the df is factor but should contain numeric columns). I am sorry for this, but I don't know how to fix this now. I hope you get the idea. Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried reshaping?  What went wrong?  You are currently drawing 2 boxplots, one for each `y`, on top of each other for each value of `x`.  If you reshape, you'll be able to dodge these apart.  As an aside, you don't need (and shouldn't use) dollar sign notation within the ggplot functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you exactly mean - I suppose, an interaction between exp/con and T1/T2?

Maybe this one is the plot you're looking for (note the `interaction` aes in the function call):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(1234)
x<- sample(c("exp", "con"), 100, replace = TRUE)
yT1<-rnorm(100)
yT2<-rnorm(100)
df1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,yT1,yT2))

df2 <- gather(df1, "grp", "val", yT1, yT2)
df2$val <- as.numeric(df2$val)

ggplot(df2, aes(x = grp, y = val, interaction = x, colour = grp)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

or as alternative, to give each group an own colour:

```
df2$newx <- sprintf("%s.%s", as.character(df2$x), df2$grp)

ggplot(df2, aes(x = newx, y = val, colour = newx)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution looks great. I still try to apply it to my data (which returns the "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data"-error). I'm working on this issue

Comment: Great! I just messed up my column/variable names. Everything's fine :) thank you so much